# Библиотека array, ввод размера массива с клавиатуры

Tags: c++, массивы, шаблоны-с++, stl

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ, используя array (int, N) name; ввести размер массива (N) с клавиатуры?

Comment: можно только взять массив с большим размером и использовать часть. Но зачем это сделать, если можно пользоваться стандартными контейнерами?

Comment: Для вашей задачи лучше использовать класс vector

Comment: Обычный массив можно (если N не слишком велико), только сначала вводите N, потом объявляете массив `int a[N]`;` (Это называется VLA -- Varible Length Array)

Comment: @avp разве в С++ есть VLA? Я думал только в Си

Comment: @EOF, g++ понимает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду

```
std::array<T,int>
```

то нет, НЕТ, **НЕТ**. Это значение должно быть известно во время компиляции!

Так же, как нельзя объявить простой массив с размером, "вводимым с клавиатуры".

Answer (score 1):

Можно сымитировать такое поведение с помощью `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    std::vector<int> mas(N);
    // Теперь у нас mas - массив, у которого ровно N элементов
    std::vector<int> mas1(N, 0);
    // Теперь у нас mas1 - массив, у которого ровно N элементов, и который дополнительно заполнен нулями
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а в первом случаи элементы чем будут инициализированы?... И причем тут сымитирование? И почему только вектор?...

Comment: Я не уверен, но судя по описанию на cppreference, скорее всего тоже будут нули... Я в английском на спец, увы -_- .

Comment: Все стандартные контейнеры инициализируют свои элементы со значением по умолчанию, если не задано это значение